# Adding new plist files to iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, plist

I have created an iOS game that consists of a number of levels within which have a number of stages that the player must complete.

Each level is pulled from a plist file which contains the data for each of the stages.

What I would like to know is what is the best way to send new plist files (i.e. new levels) to the app without having the user needing to update the entire app via the app store?

Can this be done using CloudKit? Is CloudKit appropriate for this? Is it possible to create offline plist file which the app can then pull when made available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that CloudKit will be useful for storing your users' data but can't provide app updates.

You could consider use REST apis to access the different levels on a server that you provide. This would be relatively simple and you can find lots of examples online. You could start with a single service; getLevelN etc.